# Unwanted box in blogger posts

Tags: templates, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

[blogger post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzdbb.jpg)

Any suggestions on how to remove the white box in the attached image? I have installed a customer theme and disabled comments on the page. But cant seem to get rid of the box. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Post blog URL or code!

Comment: @Bassam Hey dude! Thanks for getting in touch. Although I am not quite sure exactly where this bit of code goes. I tried placing it before </head> in 'edit html' in blogger but doesn't effect it. Here is the page by the way: http://www.socialguidez.com/p/privacy-policy.html. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Bassam I am really sorry I was pasting the code into a different blog :/. Thank you so much it worked great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have disabled comments but comments div still there and has padding and background. Paste this code before `</head>` element to hide comments div in all static pages.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "static_page"'>
  <style>
    #comments {display: none}
  </style>
</b:if>
```

Or if you want to hide the div in a specific page use the next and change page URL to your page URL.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == "page URL"'>
  <style>
    #comments {display: none}
  </style>
</b:if>
```